# Sails.js won't install. Windows

Tags: windows, npm, installation, sails.js

Sails.js will not install, but just to make sure npm is working I installed grunt
`npm install -g grunt-cli` and it installed correctly.

But when I run  `npm install -g sails` I get an error.

**Command prompt error:**

`sails@0.11.0 preinstall C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails
 node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js

Sails.js Installation - Error

Unable to check your npm-version

Please reinstall npm to use Sails.js

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600

npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-
cli.js" "-g" "install" "sails"
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! sails@0.11.0 preinstall: `node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sails@0.11.0 preinstall script 'node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the sails package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sails
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log`

**npm-debug.log:**
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c850ac8c71e0410db020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by running `npm install -g sails --ignore-scripts`.
The only thing I can think of is for some reason I don't have `./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js` file and it is trying to run it, so by ignoring it I don't get the error, hence the successful install.
I still don't understand why, but I hope this helps someone.

Comment: No, the preinstall is running, but it's having trouble parsing the npm version.  What do you get from running `npm -v` on the command line?

Comment: When I run `npm -v` I get `2.14.2`

Answer (score 2):

I got the same errors.

> npm -g install sails

But it worked when I ran command line as administrator.